# CMake file for a C++ project

Tags: c++, cmake

There is some CMake magic I don't understand. How should a CMakeLists.txt file look like for a small C++ project with directories like this:

```
.
├── bin
└── src
    ├── src
    └── test

bin      — directory for built program
src/src  — directory for source
src/test — directory for tests
```

The tests will need to include files from src/src.
I'd like to manage all the operations from cmake, however at this moment I even can't cause cmake to compile file in src/c.cpp.

Any help, links are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your CMake files should reside in the main source directory and its sub-directories. The easiest approach is to have one `CMakeLists.txt` in the `src` directory, which includes all files from `src/src` and `src/test`. A very minimalistic example could look like the following:

```
# CMakeLists.txt in src
project(myExample)
set(myExample_SOURCES
        src/file1.cpp
        src/main.cpp)
add_executable(myExecutable ${myExample_SOURCES})

set(myExample_test_SOURCES
        src/file1.cpp
        test/test_file2.cpp
        test/test_main.cpp)
add_executable(myTestSuite ${myExample_test_SOURCES})
```

The output directory is normally not specified, because you can have different active
builds in parallel with
different options, e.g. you can have one build in debug mode `-O0 -g`, another one in release mode with `-O2 -g` flags and a third one in release mode with heavy optimization flags `-O3`. Every build resides in its own directory (e.g. `build-debug`, `build-rel`, 
`build-opt`).

You should create the output directory (`bin` in your case) manually and call the `cmake` command inside this directory. As an argument you have to supply the path to the main `CMakeLists.txt`. In other words, just execute

```
cmake ../src
```

when you are inside `bin`. This will take all files from the `src` directory and put the output to the `bin` directory. 
You can easily create a second output directory, say `bin2`, where you specify different build flags. The `ccmake` provides a very minimalistic GUI for that.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to start with cmake [examples.html](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/examples.html)